# SQL Import values that have the earliest day by a specific group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 sql tables, they have the exact same structure, one is full of data.

What I wanted to do first was to grab all values that have the earliest report date for each client.  Client ID is a column that only contains 5 Clients at much.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[LDAP-NEW] ([Name], [Username (pre 2000)], [Username],[Description], [Disabled], [Last Logon Date], [Last Logon DC], [Creation Date]
    , [Modification Date], [Parent Container], [Operating System], [Operating System Version Number], [Password Last Changed], [DNS Host Name], [Primary Group]
    , [Group Membership (Direct)], [Import Date], [Hash], [Client ID], [Report Date])
SELECT [Name], [Username (pre 2000)], [Username], [Description], [Disabled],[Last Logon Date], [Last Logon DC], [Creation Date]
    , [Modification Date], [Parent Container], [Operating System], [Operating System Version Number], [Password Last Changed], [DNS Host Name], [Primary Group]
    , [Group Membership (Direct)], [Import Date], [Hash], [Client ID], MIN([Report Date])
FROM dbo.LDAP WHERE [Client ID] = 'CLIENT1'
```

Above is my last query, I first tried a group by [Client ID] but I kept getting the error:

> Column 'dbo.LDAP.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This for me made little to no sense, since my SQL knowledge is not much. I get the same error without the group by clause, just using the query above.

I want to grab all the data with the earliest report date for each client. What am I doing wrong in my query and what can I do to fix it?

As data example , client ID has 5 unique strings, but the other column have multiple rows , for example one string of clientid might have hundreds of rows between the other columns, the data is unique based on Report_Date column as for example one report date contains unique username(pre 2000)'s for that date for a client ID .

Comment: Its because you are trying to aggregate with the `min` function. To aggregate you have to be combining records in some manner, often `group by` and when aggregating all columns must either be aggregated or grouped by.

Comment: Can you provide a small example of the data that you're using? You say that there may be only 5 `Client ID`s, but what about the other columns? Can there be multiple `Name`s (or other column) per the `Client ID`, or is it just multiple rows for `Report Date`?

Answer (score 1):

Do not aggregate. Instead, you can filter on the record that has earliest date for each client:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[LDAP-NEW] (...)
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.LDAP l 
WHERE 
    [Client ID] = 'CLIENT1'
    AND [Report Date] = (
        SELECT MIN([Report Date])
        FROM dbo.LDAP l1
        WHERE l1.[Client ID] = l.[Client ID] 
    )
```

Note: for just one client, `TOP (1)` and `ORDER BY` are even simpler:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[LDAP-NEW] (...)
SELECT TOP (1) ...
FROM dbo.LDAP l 
WHERE [Client ID] = 'CLIENT1'
ORDER BY [Report Date]
```

Comment: Quick quesiton on the first, what is that l1 and 1.[CLIENT ID] those are making an error on my sql query: The multi-part identifier "l.Client ID" could not be bound.

Comment: Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(3030 rows affected) is an error after I fixed that issue

Comment: @VictorJMytre: `l1` is a *table alias*.that refers to the table being selected from in the subquery. And the message that you are seeing is a warning, not an error. Is the query producing the expected result?

Comment: it eliminated 3000 rows which had a null value at Name, and that is not a desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to easily find the earliest row.

```
INSERT INTO [LDAP-NEW] (id, dt)
SELECT s1.id, s1.dt
FROM (
    SELECT id, dt
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rn
    FROM LDAP
) s1
WHERE s1.rn = 1
;
```

... would give you an `INSERT` of only the most recent records by the `id`.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=56553575b0e80cead668884bd7828b9d

Modify the `PARTITION BY` and the `ORDER BY` for your specific criteria. Then you can just `SELECT` the columns that you need.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5c96d78200741eb089fa44fa601510dd